# Animating parts of an image

Tags: android, animation

for my bachelors thesis I'm creating a wearable that detects the position it has been placed on on the body.
It is connected to the Android device via BLE and tells the phone where it has been placed.

Now I want to show a "map" of the body and animate a blinking dot (I call in indicatorfrom now on) or something on the body where the wearable is placed. It could be multiple devices on different places of the body. If a new device is placed on the body it should blink on the body-map.

I have read about [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) which is kind of impractical, because I would have to create too many different frames. [Tweened view animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) sounded good at first but i would need access to every single indicator. I also tried creating the animation with a canvas wich actually would work out, but I would have to redraw a lot to get good animations.

I usually develop web frontends, so I thought maybe just absolutely positioning the indicators on a background image and then telling each indicator if it should be visible or if it should blink etc. would be a good approach. So i tried to realize this with a layer-list of drawables, giving each an id. Then I could manipulate each single one. But i couldn't get it to work.

I could also go with OpenGL but that would be way too much overhead i guess.

So my question is what would be the best way to create multiple separately controllable things placed absolutely on a background image. Any thoughts on that?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SurfaceView ( in know you mentioned that ), but then paint a background bitmap of the body on the SurfaceView. That would give you the body.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29

Then all you have to do is render the dots.

Note that if this is simple enough you may be able to get away with overriding the onDraw of an ImageView instead of implementing a SurfaceView with a background thread.

Hope this helps, sounds like a fun project.

Comment: That is not exactly an answer to my question. But I guess that's what I am going to do.

Answer (score 0):

I figured there is an Absolute layout, but it was deprecated in API level 3.

So for now i go with this:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/figure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/man"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beSeen_arm_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:clickable="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beSeen_arm_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beSeen_forearm_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beSeen_forearm_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beSeen_back_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beSeen_head"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is not the best, I guess it has pretty much the same downsides as the AbsoluteLayout had.

Something like % instead of dp would be nice for the margin I guess.